# Detect combined keys pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, key, detect

I want to detect if the user clicked few keys together (example: ctrl+c , alt +F4 etc..)

How can I do it?

I googled it but I couldnt get any right answer

I the following code:

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys == (Keys.C) &&Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

But it didn't worked, any ideas?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: How did you determine it doesn't work? where did you call that from? Are you using Windows Forms, WPF, or what?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I am using Windows Forms

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is incorrent use this:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
{
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said here:
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.C) && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
            {
            }
        }
But I got this error:
Error 1 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'KeyCode' and no extension method 'KeyCode' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The timer_tick EventArgs does not contain the KeyDownEventArgs. You can only capture them in the KeyDownEvent

Comment: You have an extra `)`

Answer (score 1):

I just understood what I was should to do:
I was needed to type this:

```
void detectCopy(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
    {
        //work here
    }
}
```

and this on the constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(detectCopy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the constructor do this:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(detectCopy);
        KeyPreview = true;
    }
```

And in the code do this:

```
void detectCopy(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
    {
    //work here
    }
}
```

In Windows Form, the Propertie KeyPreview need be true to KeyDown Event works!!!